# Woocommerce: How to move price in single product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have tried the following but it didn't change anything.

```
// Move WooCommerce price
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 45 );
```

Comment: this code is working fine, I double checked it make sure your theme is not overriding it with the same logic and assigning it different priority number.

Comment: I have tried even higher priority numbers such as 95 and 195 but the price doesn't budge :/

Comment: what I mean, I'm sure you are writing it in functions.php but maybe your theme is overwriting it after you write this function, can you tell me which theme you are using? furthermore, if the theme is overriding it then you need to remove that priority not the priority by woocommerce.